# How could I calculate my (theoretical) candidate score automatically?

Tags: discussion

We did it! We had the [first election](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/election/1) (well, kind of) and we have a new moderator! I figured what the [candidate score](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252641/what-are-the-details-on-the-candidate-score-which-shows-during-an-election) is

> The Candidate Score can range from 0 to 40, and is calculated as follows:
>
> - 1 point for each 1000 reputation up to 20,000 reputation for a maximum of 20 points.
> - 1 point each for Moderation badges - Civic Duty, Cleanup, Deputy, Electorate, Marshal, Reviewer, Sportsmanship, Steward - for a maximum of 8 points.
> - 1 point each for Editing badges - Copy Editor, Explainer, Organizer, Refiner, Strunk and White, Tag
>   Editor - for a maximum of 6 points.
> - 1 point each for Participation badges - Constituent, Convention, Enthusiast, Investor, Quorum, Yearling - for a maximum of 6 points.
>
> For badges that can be awarded multiple times only 1 point is granted for each badge type, thus ensuring a maximum score of 40 points.

My question: **How can I obtain *automatically* the candidate score for a given user, without counting manually for a given user?**

Comment: I found https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/298418/candidate-score?UserIds= which points in the correct direction but somehow I did not manage to query my userID for astronomy SE.

Comment: Hmmm, when I ran a query regarding your candidate score, it worked. Maybe you accidentally had the site set to SO, see the options below the Run Query button. You should get 13 as the output.